# What is the hardest to kill zombie that can spawn naturally?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm on a server with hard difficulty, and I made a general mob XP grinder. I'm adding a mode where it can be turned into an AFKable loot farm. It will extend the drop, and make the total fall X blocks long. My question is: what is the minimum amount of fall that will kill anything? Zombies can have diamond armor... and that can be enchanted. Can it be protection 4, feather falling 4? Or can zombies not get that powerfully naturally spawned? I checked the wiki, couldn't find an answer.

If anyone who knows the technical side of Minecraft, or lead me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated!

Also, person who downvoted within 3 seconds of me posting this, can you tell me why?

Comment: Don't worry about single downvotes, there will always be someone who has a bad day or whatever.

Comment: Chicken jockies never die on falls. This has screwed me up many times.

Comment: @John that should probably be in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Minecraft wiki lists the maximum enchantment level for zombie armour as 22 [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Geared_zombies) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Zombie&oldid=1481318#Geared_zombies)). That can at most give the zombie Protection 3 on all pieces and Feather falling 4 on the boots, according to [this very useful enchantment chart](https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/minecraft_gamepedia/0/0c/Book_Enchant_Probability_Chart.png).

That together with their natural armour points can make them quite resistant to fall damage. I just tested it with this command:

```
summon zombie ~ ~-3 ~ {ArmorItems:[{id:"diamond_boots",Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"protection",lvl:3},{id:"feather_falling",lvl:4}]}},{id:"diamond_leggings",Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"protection",lvl:3}]}},{id:"diamond_chestplate",Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"protection",lvl:3}]}},{id:"diamond_helmet",Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"protection",lvl:3}]}}]}
```

It can survive a 103 block deep fall, so you would have to make your drop distance 104 blocks. If you really want to do this and stand at the bottom, you can at most make your spawn platform a circle with radius 74, because outside of that radius (128 blocks away from you), nothing spawns. And that still doesn't kill baby zombies on chickens.

Fun fact: Zombies can use totems of undying when they hold them, that means that if your mob farm is in a village and you somehow make a raid spawn inside of it and an evoker dies, drops a totem and a zombie picks it up, then no fall height will be enough. And chickens. Chickens are much more likely and are also not killed by fall.

How about just using magma blocks instead?
Or lava, under that a sign, under that a slab, under that a hopper. That way you automatically collect all drops and you can make sure that all monsters are killed, except for witches. If you also want to kill witches, you could use 23 minecarts in one space, that way every mob that falls into it is extremely quickly crammed to death, too fast for witches to drink their potions.

Answer (score -1):

Found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/7k10rh/rarest_mob_on_minecraft_at_least_theorically/

> a left-handed leader baby villager chicken jockey that can pick up items, has full diamond gear, each part enchanted at level 8, an iron sword enchanted at the same level, on Halloween and under very specific conditions. Oh, and you have just a miniscule 0.000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 001 991 202 975% to witness it.

Ok, maybe I don't need to prepare for *worst* case scenario, as we can go back on some of the calculations here and show that from a functional and health standpoint, it's still pretty rare for a zombie that I'd have a ton of trouble with to spawn.

Comment: Please try to summarize the relevant information contained in the link; we try to ensure that even if the linked site goes down, answers here are minimally affected.

Comment: Being left handed, or being a villager, or it being halloween, or a bunch of other things, don't make the zombie harder to kill.

Comment: I think the point of it was that it would be a chicken jockey with full god tier diamond armor, and a very good sword. Yes, the information you pointed out is extraneous, but it doesn't need to be thrown out, it just makes for some interesting extra information. Because the answer the OP provided has information on armor and weapon stats which directly answered their question (or at least provided more info about it), the extraneous information does not detract from the answer.